# Referring and assigning column by variable name in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to update a column in data.table by referring to its name with a variable, and I can't figure out how.

```
> a = data.table(id=c(1,2),val=c(3,4))
> a
   id val
1:  1   3
2:  2   4
> j="val"
> a[id==1,..j]
   val
1:   3
> a[id==1,(j):=5]
> a
   id val
1:  1   5
2:  2   4
> a[id==1,(j):=..j+1]
Error in ..j + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I expected this last one to result in setting column j ("val") equal to the value of column j plus 1, e.g. the result should be:

```
> a
   id val
1:  1   6
2:  2   4
```

I'm sure this question's been asked before as this seems really simple, but I can't seem to find the right thing to google to make sense of it.

Comment: `a[id==1,(j):=get(j)+1]`

Comment: Do you know why the syntax for referring to a variable is different depending on whether it's on the right or left side of the assignment? I'm sure there's a good technical reason, but as a non-expert it's incredibly unintuitive.

Comment: For one, `get` on the LHS has no meaning, since it returns the *value* of an object, not a reference to the object's memory location. It works well on the right because it follows basic R object-search semantics (and therefore does not require special treatment/methods in `data.table`). The analogy might be `assign`, though I generally discourage use of that function in all but very specific circumstances (I have not tested its use within `data.table` assignment RHS).

Comment: yet another question that would benefit from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the columns in `.SDcols` and subset with `.SD`

```
a[id==1,(j):= .SD[[1]] +1, .SDcols = j]
```